# Applying Custom Resolution to VirtualBox VM causes VM to Abort on Startup

Tags: windows, command-line, virtualbox, virtual-machine, display

I am running Windows 11 Pro 22H2, hosting a virtual machine running Windows 10 Home. VirtualBox's UI shows 1920x1200 as the largest guest resolution. I've attempted to change the resolution to match the resolution of my monitor, 3440x1440, using VBoxManage. I've taken the instructions from [here](https://winaero.com/set-exact-display-resolution-in-virtualbox-virtual-machine/) and ran the following:

```
.\VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution any
.\VBoxManage setextradata "Windows10VM" "CustomVideoMode1" "3440 x 1440 x 32"
.\VBoxManage controlvm "Windows10VM" setvideomodehint 3440 1440 32
```

This worked well until turning off the VM. Upon attempting to reboot the VM, the session immediately aborts, giving the following error:

```
Failed to construct device 'vga' instance #0 (VERR_VGA_INVALID_CUSTOM_MODE).
Result Code: E_FAIL (0X80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {6ac83d89-6ee7-4e33-8ae6-b257b2e81be8}
```

Is there a work around that'll allow me to keep my resolution at 3440x1440 without bricking my VM?

Comment: If you have the guest extensions installed properly, the resolution should become automatic.  No?  I know you still set it for the VM but as soon as the guest stuff kicks in, it should match the window size.  I have never used such a high resolution for a virtualbox vm so perhaps I have no idea what I am talking about :P  Make sure you have enough video memory specified in the VM settings..

Comment: Have you installed the VBox Guest Additions? See [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox).